# Material-UI: Grid items with same height

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I want to bring these grid items to the same height, but not to stretch them.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is how I want it:

[image]

But I can only do that by manually setting the image width therefore it's not responsive. The users are able to replace this image so setting fixed dimensions is not an option. Any help is appreciated. Here is the minimum code needed to reproduce (I have removed the content within the card to keep the code minimal):

**Note: I have used material-ui v4**

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
   <Grid item lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
      <Grid container spacing={3} className="mb-3">
         <Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
            <Card
               className="justify-between items-center p-sm-24 bg-paper dashboard-card"
               elevation={6}
               >
            </Card>
         </Grid>
         <Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
            <Card
               className="justify-between items-center p-sm-24 bg-paper dashboard-card"
               elevation={6}
               >
            </Card>
         </Grid>
         <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <Card className="bg-paper" elevation={6}>
               <CardContent className="flex justify-center">
                  <img
                  src={this.state.logo}
                  alt="logo"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  />
               </CardContent>
            </Card>
         </Grid>
      </Grid>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: did you checked with `style={{ object-fit:  'contain' }}`

Comment: @SteveGomez I tried maxHeight on the image but it won't be responsive. That's the problem I have. The users are able to replace this image so setting fixed dimensions is not an option. That's why I need a solution that ensures responsiveness. I'll add this part to the question too.

Comment: @PrashantJangam Yeah I did. It did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but it worked for me. So I'm answering my own question.

Instead of using an image tag, I used the CardMedia component which allows to set the height to match the other cards and it is also responsive.

> you might want to display a video or a responsive image. Use the component prop for these use cases

```
<CardMedia
  component="img"
  alt="green iguana"
  height="140"
  image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
  />
```

More info: https://mui.com/components/cards/#media